# Ajax posting HttpPostFileBase from MVC view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a form which gets a file, this all works.  The form post controller does a check that looks for the existence of a file with the same name already in the database, and if one exists, passes the HttpPostFileBase object to its view as the model.

The view consists of a modal popup that prompts the user to confirm an overwrite.  Upon answering yes, the view should post to a new controller action to actually upload the file and store information in a database.

```
@model System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase
....
'Yes': function (modal) {
    //Post to UploadFile
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Media", new { area = "Manage" })',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: @locationid, file: @Model }
    });
    modal.closeModal();
},
```

When I look at the generated source on the page, the data has become this:

```
data: { id: 1, file: System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper }
```

UploadFile is expecting what I passed however, HttpPostedFileBase

```
private void UploadFile(int locationid, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

Before we get there though, javascript throws an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

So I added

```
@using System.Web
```

thinking perhaps it just didn't understand what System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper was.  This didn't help at all.  Anyone have any suggestions as to how better to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `@Model` in the view like that it is going to try to output to the page a string representation of the model.  .NET does this internally by calling `.ToString()` on the object.  By default, `.ToString()` for reference types will return the name of the type.  In this case, that's `"System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper"`.  So that's what's being emitted to your JavaScript code.

Adding a `@using` directive doesn't change that.  That's all server-side behavior.  The error you're seeing is because the raw string `System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper` doesn't mean anything in JavaScript.  So the JavaScript parser doesn't know what to do with it.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish here and why?  I may be wrong about what you're trying to do, but here goes...

It looks like you're trying to emit *the entire posted file* to the JavaScript, only to post it back to the server unchanged.  First of all, this probably isn't going to work the way you think it would.  But more importantly, if you already have the file server-side and you're just asking the user to confirm something about the file, then there's no reason to pass the whole file back to the user again just to have them pass it back to the server again.

Instead of trying to emit the entire model to the JavaScript, only emit some kind of identifier for the file.  Where do you store the file server-side and how do you uniquely identify it?  If there's some identifier (let's say an integer from a database record for the sake of example) then you only need that identifier client-side.  You can wrap it in a view model of some kind to make it easy to add more functionality if needed.  Something like:

```
public class FileConfirmationModel
{
    public int FileID { get; set; }
}
```

If you pass that model to the view, with the `FileID` property set, then in the view you can use that ID in your JavaScript code:

```
data: { id: @locationid, file: @Model.FileID }
```

(By the way, where does `@locationid` come from?  Maybe these should all be on one view model?)

Then in your server-side code for that AJAX handler you would find the file you already have based on the ID and do whatever you need to do with that file.

Comment: I see the problem with @Model now.    Sadly, that is what I'm trying to do, though I know its not ideal :) The problem is that we can't store the file until one of two conditions is met, 1 - we confirm there is no file by that name in the database, 2 - we confirm there is a file by that name and the user approves an overwrite.  We can't do a db query until we know the name of the file, and there is no way to prompt the user from the controller for overwrite permission.  I think I'm best off attempting to sell a 'Overwrite if exists' checkbox on the original form page given this answer, thanks

Comment: @ItinerantEngineer: Another alternative might be to store the file server-side, but store it only in a temporary location until the user confirms.  Or perhaps always store files, but in an overwrite scenario you change all pointers to the old file to point to the new file (IDs, filenames, however the files are identified).  That would have the added benefit of keeping the old files around for any need of an "undo overwrite" scenario.